# How do I send a push notification using Push API with Vapid keys in Postman?

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman, push-api, vapid

How do I send a push notification in postman, if I have the vapid keys and the subscriber? I have already configured the service worker, so thats not the question. I just want to send a simple request to test if it works.

For demonstrating purposes, here is my data in JSON-Format:

**Vapid Keys**

```
{
  "publicKey": "BPqcNuGC7sENCAIEBJ-b...";
  "privateKey": "DxuK61Dz...";
}
```

**An example subscriber**

```
{
  "endpoint": "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/f6uPibFfDko:APA91...",
  "auth": "uzsYiokjDSV5...",
  "p256dh": "BPoneR3IDkTRoeCYmQAUUZ/tIAcXMfF5IrrCZWQp4wygQWhHyYxMD4jBUV/H..."
}
```

Comment: I have the same question. Have you ever figured it out ?

Comment: Unfortunately I dont think so. It was some time ago, thats why I can't remember.